# Adding plugins to a videojs component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, single-page-application, video.js

I'm currently working on making a image and video carousel in VueJS with video-player as the component handling the videos. It's supposed to load videos from multiple sources. I found the videoJS resolution switcher which apparently can do that but I don't know where to register the plugin because if I register it in the player options property:

```
playerOptions:{    
    sources:[
        {
            src: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4', 
            type: 'video/mp4',            
        }
    ],                                 
    width: 1366,
    controls: false, 
    autoplay: true,
    preload: true,       
    plugins:{
        videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
            default: 'high',
            dynamicLabel: true
        }
    }             
}
```

This gives me the error that the plugin doesn't exist. I have already installed the plugin via npm. So how do I add this plugin to the player?

*EDIT* adding my template in case anyone needs to see this. Also tweaking the title of the question for clarity

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-carousel :cycle="cycleValue" :interval="carouselInterval" :hide-delimiters= "true" :show-arrows="false" :continuous="true">
            <v-carousel-item v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :src = "slide.content " :key=i>
            </v-carousel-item>
            <v-carousel-item>
               <video-player :options="playerOptions" @play="pauseCarousel($event)" @ended="playCarousel($event)" ref="videoPlayer" ></video-player>
            </v-carousel-item>
        </v-carousel>               
    </div> 
</template>
```

Comment: I'd want to see your html to be able to answer for certain.  Do you reference that plugin in your html?  You need to.

Comment: I'm doing this in VueJS so I assume you want to see my template. I added it to the question.